# how to perform an event on success using gulp-jslint-simple

Tags: javascript, gulp, jslint, gulp-watch

I'm using the [gulp-jslint-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jslint-simple) plugin to jslint my javascript on save, which works fine with the following code below:

```
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(jslint.run({
            node: true,
            vars: true
        }))
        .pipe(jslint.report({
            reporter: require(stylish).reporter
        }));
});
```

this basically applies jslint to all of the folders within my javascript directory refered to as `paths.js`.

I use the following watch method to listen out for a javascript file being saved:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['lint']);
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['js']);
});
```

I have another watch method as specified above which concats and minifies the javascript in the same files, however i only want this to run if the jslinting returned no errors, Is this possible?

I've tried adding an `.on('error', errorHandler)` method but this only gets hit on error, where as i want the success method. I've also looked into `.on('end', ..)` however this appears to be hit multiple times some how.

so in a nutshell, i want to be able to do the following in gulp:

```
if (gulp.watch(paths.js, ['lint'])) {
    //somehow call this..
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['js']);
});
```

Comment: do you want to call another gulp task or just do some js work?

Comment: @Callistino i have a js function that minifies files, this works fine, i want it to run only if the 'lint' task is successful

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `lint` task fail when there are lint errors using the `emitError` option, and then you can make the `js` task depend on the `lint` task:

```
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(jslint.run({
            node: true,
            vars: true
        }))
        .pipe(jslint.report({
            reporter: require(stylish).reporter,
            emitError: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('js', ['lint'], function() {
  //js stuff
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['js']);
});
```

Comment: with the above, the 'js' function appears to continue executing regardless of the errors found in the ['lint'] call, ideally the 'js' would not be called if the ['lint'] wasn't successful (error free)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `return` in the `lint` task.

Comment: thanks, but the only way this works is if i dont handle the error that we emit, so it basically crashes gulp. Which we don't want, if i handle the error with `.on('error', errorHandler)` and have the following in the handler function `this.emit('end');` it doesn't crash but continues to run the 'js' function, is this anything to do with my 'js' function? i was under the impression that it didnt matter what went in there as long as `['lint']` passed successfully?

Comment: You can keep gulp from crashing by catching the exception with something like `process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) { ... })`, but that's no guarantee that the gulp process will be in a usable state.

Comment: @Ben can't you set a global flag on the `errorHandler`, then you execute your js function when the flag is not set inside the 'js' task.